# AWS Elemental MediaLive CreateInput IAM policy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-media-live, aws-mediaservices

I'm trying to setup an AWS IAM policy to create MediaLive inputs.

I'm running this through the simulator

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "medialive:CreateInput",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:input:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I get `Implicitly denied (no matching statements).` error.

Of course that, if I try to use the following policy, I get successful in the simulation, but this is not a good implementation because of the wide range of resources.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "medialive:CreateInput",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried to include `"arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:inputSecurityGroup:*"` and `"arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:channel:*"` next to the already existing resource, but I still get the error message.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Specify *input-security-group* resource ARN for the *CreateInput action*, in order to have the simulation to succeed.

Can you please confirm if you have used the following syntax or similar when testing it through the [aws IAM Policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "medialive:CreateInput",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:medialive:us-west-2:XXXXXXX:input:*",
                "arn:aws:medialive:*:XXXXXXXX:inputSecurityGroup:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: User used for simulating this IAM Policy needs to have appropriate role/rights to create MediaLive resources. [MediaLive UserGuide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/medialive-ug.pdf) has detailed steps on how to create it.

Comment: Yes, I confirm I tried your suggestion and it does not work.

Comment: Looks like the user that you are using to simulate the IAM policy does not have MediaLive Access/Rights.

Comment: User you are using for this simulation needs to have the rights to create EML resources. Please follow the MediaLive UserGuide to create this policy as per your requirement. [Page 11 onwards]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/medialive-ug.pdf